# Use the same path for windows and ubuntu google drive?

Tags: partitioning, windows, 22.04, sync, google-drive

So I just set up Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my XPS 9500 next to Windows. Everything working fine. Next, I tried to access the Google Drive files on my Windows partition, which also works fine. Of course, however, the syncing is not done until I log in back to Windows. Thus, I was looking for a way to get Google Drive sync onto my Ubuntu.

I found this great way of setting up a synced folder (without having to pay for any external software). In the Ubuntu settings, simply go to "online accounts" (from the package gnome-online-accounts) and connect your Google account. This automatically creates a mountable drive in your file browser, which immediately starts syncing with your Google Drive. The location of this Google Drive folder obviously is a different one than the one on the Windows partition. So, this would simply use up unnecessary extra space on my Linux partition to create exactly the same files that are already on the Windows partition inside the GD folder.

My question is whether there is a way to set the default path where Ubuntu is copying the synced files to the location of my Google Drive on the Windows partition? Then, the two systems would share the same folder for Google Drive and whenever I log in to one of the two, I can simply work on the files from there and they will be synced.

Thanks!